# Filtering Linq to Entity on Lazy Loading 3 levels Nested Query

Tags: entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

Assuming a Entity Framework, in a LazyLoading context.

We have 3 entities:

- Product(which has many Order Details)
- OrderDetails(which has many Details)
- Detail

The following query brings all **Products** with Name=Books. And to each of these products loads  all the **OrderDetails** which OrderDetail.Quantity>5.

```
var query = anEntityManager.Products.Where(p => p.Name == "Books")
.Select(p => new { Product = p, OrderDetails = p.OrderDetails.Where(od => od.Quantity >       5) });
var results = query.ToList();
var products = results.Select( x => x.Product);
```

My Problem is that the **Details** of each **OrderDetail** are NOT being retrieved from DB. How can I make an Include in this query so **Details** are also loaded from DB in the same query?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to extend your projection:

```cs
var query = anEntityManager.Products.Where(p => p.Name == "Books")
    .Select(p => new
    {
        Product = p,
        OrderDetails = p.OrderDetails.Where(od => od.Quantity > 5),
        Details = p.OrderDetails.Where(od => od.Quantity > 5)
                                .SelectMany(od => od.Details)
    });
var results = query.ToList();
var products = results.Select( x => x.Product);
```

Using `Include` in a projection is not supported, so this (a bit ugly) code is the only way I know of to get the result in one database query.

You can probably also use `Select` instead of `SelectMany` (`Details` would then be an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Detail>>` instead of a flat `IEnumerable<Detail>`) because you are throwing away the projected properties anyway - except the `Product` property.